# GEE interaction term in R

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations

Hi I am troubling with interaction terms in R.
I am using geeglm in geepack package.

I would test interaction brain activity by region, hemisphpere, and groups.

This is my R code,

```
geeglm(beta ~ group + group * region + group * hemisphere + group * region * hemisphere + Age, id=subid, data=csd2, family=gaussian,corstr="ar1")
```

**beta** is DV, and I wanna testing those model fit.

Is it okay to use?
and how I use post hoc test in this analysis?

Please help my work..

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the formula as group * region * hemispere will test the effects of all those variables and their interactions, so you can shorten the `geeglm` call to:

```
geeglm(beta ~ Age + group * region * hemisphere, id=subid, data=csd2, family=gaussian,corstr="ar1")
```

What post hoc tests are relevant depends on what your hypotheses are. Interaction plots are usually helpful to visualize those effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!